# How to set the background color of an RTF edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, rtf

I thought it was simple but after 2 hours of googling and trying I am still at the same point.
I am trying to set a custom background color using plain Win32 C++ for a RTF Edit control.

Do you know how can I do this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: This might be of relevance? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774228(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR` Message. More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774228(v=vs.85).aspx